# How to safely copy file while another app writing in it, make sure both program not crash

Tags: c#, .net

I am managing a 3rd party vendor application which creates  .txt files and write user logs into this .txt file, there are total of 10 log files, each has max size of 100 mb, when all reached max limit, vendor app wipes of the oldest one and start writing user logs into this one. To have a safe and permanent copy of all the files I create a C# console app which to copies these log files(txt) and paste into another safe location couple times in a day. However when my console app runs to copy the .txt log files sometimes it overlap with vendor app writing time, and vendor app crashes with an error:

> "Unable to get the write to the current log file. Error: The process
>   can not access the file 'C:\FileLocation\Log01.txt' because it is
>   being used by another process. Please makes sure that the log files
>   are not open in any other application".

I am wondering if there is anyway to copy whatever in the log file, and vendor app still has access to log file to write logs. Because when vendor app crashes, it stop writing logs into .txt file, and this can cause a huge issue.

Comment: For example, create a global or class level `Queue<string>`, _Enqueue_ the busy files in the `IOException` in a `try..catch` block, try again with the queued files after a while using the `Peek` method, _Dequeue_ the successfully copied files.

Comment: When opening a file, you can choose to allow sharing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare). However that only applies if you are the one first getting that file handle - before or between the 3rd Party App. However I am not sure how wide this share is. And if the 3rd party app will not throw an exception because it can not get a exclusive lock on the file.

Comment: Why don't you copy just the the logs the 3rd party is done with? If your need to run all the time, you could use a FileSystemWatcher to determine that a new log file has been created, then copy the last before this new one.

Comment: @JQSOFT thanks for your recommendation, however I do not have any problem on my console app, it does check if the file in use or not, if it is in use it skip it and wait for next run to copy. But the problem arise when my console app sees the file is not in use, and starts copying it, within that milliseconds 3rd party vendor app wants to write log then BOOOMMMM

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your suggestion, I thought about your solution, however I need to get the copy of the current log file, whatever the log it has, because 3rd party vendor app may crush at any time for other reasons and current log files has the data what the user was doing before it crash, or what caused the crash. And when the 3rd party app crashes we can not access the log files unless we moved them into a safe location.

Comment: uhh, the 3rd party app is the one who causing the BOM BOM. Any chance to ask the vendor to check a file before writing to it since he is BOM BOMing us?

Comment: @JQSOFT unfortunately we do not have that luxury and they do not support any changes. But our company depends on this 3rd party vendor app. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading and writing bytes instead of using the `File.Copy(...)` method. It works for me in similar situations such as backing up shared local databases over networks. Hopefully it works for you.

```cs
var srcPath = "SourcePath...";
var desFile = "DestinationPath...";            
var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
var bytesRead = 0;

using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream srb = new BufferedStream(sr))
using (FileStream sw = new FileStream(desFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream swb = new BufferedStream(sw))
{
    while(true)
    {
        bytesRead = srb.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (bytesRead == 0) break;
        swb.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    swb.Flush();
}
```

Good day.

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine so far, knock on the wood.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency problem. There is many ways to solve that, but all of them won't make the file just copy when another app is acessing that, this is impossible.

Try this website: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/ch01.html

You can also make all copies in the same system, it makes easer. But you will need to check if the file is open from another program.