# System.IO.Copy operation intermittently giving Access Denied Error in .Net 4.0 C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, access-denied, file-copying

I have a console application written in .Net framework 4.0 C#. In the application I am copying a file from one location of the server to another location.

Here is the code:

```
System.IO.File.Copy("sourceFile","destFile",true);
```

I have created a Windows scheduler which executes the console app everyday at a particular time.

The code works perfectly fine if I run it manually. However it intermittently gives below access denied error (say once in every 10 times) while running it through scheduler.

*Error Message: **Access to the path "destFile" is denied**. Other information(if any) 
Stack Trace:  at Syste.IO._Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at Syste.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName,Boolean overwrite,Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName,String destFileName,Boolean overwrite)*

I tried to reproduce the error in other lower environment servers (Dev/Test), but the issue could not be reproduced. Have already deleted the task scheduler and created fresh ones many times, but no luck. The issue gets fixed once I rerun the code as it is totally intermittent in nature. Permission to the source and destination location is already given because of which it works fine 9/10 times.

Pls advise if you see any issue or need additional information for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Is it possible the target file is used by some other process, so it cannot be overwritten?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311176/how-to-safely-copy-file-while-another-app-writing-in-it-make-sure-both-program/59313972#59313972) way.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to the application user permissions, probably the user which you are using to run your application, misses the permissions to write in your desired path.

Comment: Permission looks correct as it runs fine 9/10 times without this error.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you turned on overwrite option. If one of the dest files(being overwritten) are opened by other applications, you will get some error messages.

Comment: There are no other applications which can open the dest file before the console application accesses it. However is there a chance that the windows scheduler can run a duplicate instance of the same console app in parallel ?

Comment: How often does it run? If it runs before the previous job ends, the previous job can hold the some of the dest files

Comment: It runs once daily for approximately 25 minutes.